# Escaping filenames in for loop?

Tags: batch-file

So, I have a batch file that runs a program called `Kid3`. The thing is that due to the way `Kid3` processes commands from batch and filenames, it seems as the characters need to be escaped some way. Here is an example with the program trying to operate on some files from a game I'm working on:

> Unknown command 'select 03_A_Hero's_Return.ogg', -h for help.
>   Unknown command 'select 03_Battle's_Advent.ogg', -h for help.
>   MP4Modify failed
>   Error while writing file:
>   E:/RPGMaker/Games/AnimaMV/dev/AnimaMV/audio/bgm/03_Battle_Agains_Demon.4a

I am not sure about why the error of writing the file occurred, but I'm guessing it's because of drive errors I need to scan and fix. However, the main focus here is the "unknown command" bar at the top. Here is a sample of my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (bgm bgs me se) do (
  cd %%x
  for /r %%D in (*.ogg) DO (
    title Fixing sound %%x\"%%~nD.m4a"
    if exist "%%~nD.mp4" (
      if not exist "%%~nD.m4a" (
        ren "%%~nD.mp4" "%%~nD.m4a"
      ) else (
        del "%%~nD.mp4" 
      ) )
    %k3path% -c "select %%~nxD" -c copy -c "select %%~nD.m4a" -c paste
    pause >nul
    )
  cd ..
)
```

Note that the `pause >nul` command was only there to capture the error messages. I know I could have redirected the output to a file, which I tried but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I don't know the console application called with `%k3path%` but I suppose the command line should be `"%k3path%" -c select "%%~nxD" -c copy -c select "%%~nD.m4a" -c paste`, i.e. double quotes only around the file names and not including the command `select`.

Comment: @Mofi %k3path% is the kid3 application

Comment: @Mofi that seemed to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (bgm bgs me se) do (
  cd %%x
  for /r %%D in (*.ogg) DO (
    title Fixing sound %%x\"%%~nD.m4a"
    if exist "%%~nD.mp4" (
      if not exist "%%~nD.m4a" (
        ren "%%~nD.mp4" "%%~nD.m4a"
      ) else (
        del "%%~nD.mp4" 
      ) )
    %k3path% -c select "%%~nxD" -c copy -c select "%%~nD.m4a" -c paste
    pause >nul
    )
  cd ..
)
```